# Can I get google-services.json only with google cloud ( without firebase)

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am developing a flutter application. I need to integrate google sign in. I only use google cloud( I dont need firebase. I have created goolge signin in a react project and it works fine.). When I sign in, idtoken is return as null. I think the issue is I don't have google-services.json.

But how can I get a google-services.json?

Comment: and where u want save the user data?

Comment: @NasrAl-Rahbi I have my own database and backend. I need only to authenticate user via google-sign-in

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add google sign in without firebase cuz u need google-service from it, and user authentication should save it in Firebase.
there in no other way.


And user auth should save it in Firebase.

Like This:

[image]